# Detect Internet Explorer on Windows RT vs. Windows (Intel)

Tags: browser, user-agent, windows-rt

We have a Click Once app that does not run on Windows RT, but does run on Windows (x86/x64).  We have a detection page that checks several prerequisites to determine if the user can run the app, before offering it to them.

Everything works until a Windows RT user comes in.  Our current code sees that as "Windows" and thinks we're good, when we're not.

What is the "right" way to detect Windows RT - do we have to rely on the `ARM` token (cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920767(v=vs.85).aspx), or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I just looked for the `ARM` token, which seems to work well enough even though it relies on User Agent sniffing (which is of course horrible terrible no good very bad).